# Forbidden issue with wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp, require-once

My wamp work perfectly fine. localhost, phpmyadmin and all the other php,html etc files are accessible through localhost url. But when ever I try to access an php file which have `require_once("config.php");`  reference to any other php file it gives the following error:

> You don't have permission to access /myfolder/myfile.php/" .
>   $requests_url . " on this server.

e.g.

```
<?php
    /* Works fine*/
    echo "Test";
 ?>
```

```
<?php
   /* Give forbidden error*/
   require_once("config.php");
   echo "Test";
?>
```

I have already allow all the permission and settings that has to be done in http.confiq apachi setting file. It look like this now,

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes  ExecCGI 
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Comment: You  just need to check whether your WAMP server is online or not.

Comment: Check .htaccess files in www and directories, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have - well - permissions set wrong :)
I don't think apache config has anything to do with it.
Maybe you should have options to start wamp as superuser
( i think it should be under right click on the executable, of course, 
provided you checked and rechecked permissions for that file ten times)